# On restart webapplication in visual studio, static objects still exist

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, startup

The application I'm creating needs some storage of data in the cache. But when developping this application I need a reinitialize of this static class. This normally happens when you click the 'start debugging' button.

But sometimes when I restart the application the static information is still present on the 'session'. How can I avoid this problem?

How comes on starting / stopping / starting the webapplication still has the information of the previous run.

I have tried clearing the static object in the WebApiConfig file but when I place a breakpoint in this class it isn't always called on startup.

Btw using Visual studio 2012

Thanks in advance

Comment: Restart of your debug session, does not mean: restart of your IIS. It could be/is still running. And exactly that's the reason why the static objects do exist...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The development web server is not restartet each time you start debugging. This is why the process stays alive and with it your static class. Check the corresponding system tray icon and shut it down there to force a restart.